# Upload Magento2 extension on marketplace which have third party library dependency

Tags: extensions, marketplace, magento2.3.x

I've created a Magento2 extension which has a dependency with the 3rd party library. The third-party library has a composer package.
I tried to upload that extension on Marketplace but In QA review they failed my extension.

Although I have added that 3rd party library in Module `composer.json` file and also mentioned that library installation process in User Guide along with Module installation process but **Marketplace QA team did only install the extension and didn't install that library**, so that's why they are getting an error due to missing library.

**I created a support ticket for this but I didn't get any response from their side yet.**

Can anyone let me know how I can upload it to the Marketplace? What steps should I need to follow?

Comment: Wait for their response.

Comment: Does my way is right to add 3rd party library or is there any alternative?

Comment: @DJDev did you manage to resolve that issue?